# Notify user if their search criteria are met

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I developing a sale system using asp.net mvc. My search system allows users to save their search criteria and will notify them by email when a new product is posted is met their criteria. I tried the following:

The first way: Create a function to send bulk mail through gmail and I put this function in the post function. You can see the code described below to understand what I said:

```
public ActionResult PostProduct()
{ 
  ....
  var list = Check(); // get a list of user email when their search criteria are met with the posted product
  Send(list); // send email to the list
  // I don't know how long does it take to complete this function?
}
```

However, this method requires a lot of resources from the server and takes a lot of time to respond (if the number of emails up to 1000, it would be a bad thing), but I can customize the parameters into email content (such as links, images, ...)

The second way: I used a mail service (MailChimp) and I called its API successfully, sending mail seems easy but I can not adjust the input parameters. That means I can not customize the content of my email.
I would like to ask people if there is a better and wiser way of doing things than I used to. Thank for reading

Comment: `function PostProduct` is this really c# code?

Comment: It just a pseudocode example. I edited

Comment: You could store the product/customer combination in a table, and have a background process e-mail everything.

Comment: Thanks @pritaeas. The process that you said is a framework, a method..? Could you give me a name ? It will be useful for me

Comment: @Vietvo: Whether you make it yourself or find an existing framework is up to you. Asking for a suggested framework is out of scope for StackOverflow, and I am voting to close the question as such.

Comment: @Flater: I tried many ways before posting a question, but maybe I have not found the right keywords yet.

Comment: One commonly used solution is to write a Windows Service. It can run on a regular schedule, and send whatever emails are required at the time. How you define what emails are required, and keep records of what has already been sent, is up to you, but a database is an obvious way to keep track. Perhaps you already have this data (or something very similar) in your database.

Comment: Elmah.io have to send a lot of notifications and I like their implementation of how to send mass emails. You can read the blog here https://blog.elmah.io/migrating-a-topshelf-consumer-to-a-function-running-on-azure/

Comment: @AmanB Elmah is an error logging framework - it's not meant to be used for sending mass notifications to users.

Comment: @mason I did not recommend to use elmah to send emails. I said to check how they have implemented sending of mass emails :)

Comment: I use a third party (Hangfire) to run the email sending process in the background and it solve my problem. Thank you all you guys.